# Return multiple relationships with Laravel Eloquent

Tags: php, eloquent, laravel-6, eloquent-relationship

[image]I have a table called users and user have different roles the relation in table

- `role_users (id,user_id,role_id)`

now a role have different permissions for different resources

- `permissions(id,name) (permissions: edit,create)`
- `resources(id,name) (resources: post,comment,user)`

The relation of role with permission

- `role_resource_permissions (id,role_id,permission_id,resource_id)`

What I want is to do an Eloquent Query to search available permissions with the resource for the user.

how I will define relations in models for this.

Any help would be greatly appreciated

Comment: I found a bit confusing the relationship between the four models, can you make a diagram or something more visual?

Comment: @Periplo, as you said I added a diagram please, check

Answer (score 0):

Assuming your relationships are correctly created, I think this should work. Try it out and let me know how it goes:

```
$user_id = 1;
$user_data = Roles::whereHas('users', function (Builder $query) use ($user_id) {
        $query->where('id', $user_id);
    })->with(['permissions', 'resources'])->get();
```

It should return you a collection of **Roles** related to the specific user, with it's **Permissions** and **Resources**. For this to work, of course, **Roles** must have many **Users**.

This technique is documented here: https://laravel.com/docs/5.8/eloquent-relationships#querying-relationship-existence